# Using Google's apiclient to get information about the user's drive

Tags: python-2.7, get, google-drive-api, google-api-client, drive

I am trying to use Google's APICLIENT to access the resources described [HERE](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/about). That is: information about the user, the user's Drive, and system capabilities

There is no problem with the client if the Drive metadata is sought, but I cannot find any resources online as to how to use the client to perform an authenticated version of this:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/about
```

Does anyone have any know-how with this? I could use a few hints.

Answer (score 0):

You can request as is, just like how you request for listing or creating file in Drive API. You can follow either of the two:

### [v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get)

```
/**
 * Print information about the current user along with the Drive API
 * settings.
 */
function printAbout() {
  var request = gapi.client.drive.about.get();
  request.execute(function(resp) {
    console.log('Current user name: ' + resp.name);
    console.log('Root folder ID: ' + resp.rootFolderId);
    console.log('Total quota (bytes): ' + resp.quotaBytesTotal);
    console.log('Used quota (bytes): ' + resp.quotaBytesUsed);
  });
}
```

### [v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/about/get)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Your Client ID can be retrieved from your project in the Google
      // Developer Console, https://console.developers.google.com
      var CLIENT_ID = 'CLIENT_ID';

      var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];

      /**
       * Check if current user has authorized this application.
       */
      function checkAuth() {
        gapi.auth.authorize(
          {
            'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
            'scope': SCOPES.join(' '),
            'immediate': true
          }, handleAuthResult);
      }

      /**
       * Handle response from authorization server.
       *
       * @param {Object} authResult Authorization result.
       */
      function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        var authorizeDiv = document.getElementById('authorize-div');
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
          // Hide auth UI, then load client library.
          authorizeDiv.style.display = 'none';
          loadDriveApi();
        } else {
          // Show auth UI, allowing the user to initiate authorization by
          // clicking authorize button.
          authorizeDiv.style.display = 'inline';
        }
      }

      /**
       * Initiate auth flow in response to user clicking authorize button.
       *
       * @param {Event} event Button click event.
       */
      function handleAuthClick(event) {
        gapi.auth.authorize(
          {client_id: CLIENT_ID, scope: SCOPES, immediate: false},
          handleAuthResult);
        return false;
      }

      /**
       * Load Drive API client library.
       */
      function loadDriveApi() {
        gapi.client.load('drive', 'v3', getDetails);
      }

      function getDetails(){
        var request = gapi.client.drive.about.get({
          'fields': "user, storageQuota"
        });
        request.execute(function(resp) {
          console.log(resp)
        });

      }

      /**
       * Append a pre element to the body containing the given message
       * as its text node.
       *
       * @param {string} message Text to be placed in pre element.
       */
      function appendPre(message) {
        var pre = document.getElementById('output');
        var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
        pre.appendChild(textContent);
      }

    </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=checkAuth">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="authorize-div" style="display: none">
      <span>Authorize access to Drive API</span>
      <!--Button for the user to click to initiate auth sequence -->
      <button id="authorize-button" onclick="handleAuthClick(event)">
        Authorize
      </button>
    </div>
    <pre id="output"></pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

The only difference is that in `v3`, it requires you to add a parameter `fields` that will only return the fields you included in the parameter like `user` - The authenticated user, or `storageQuota` - The user's storage quota limits and usage. All fields are measured in bytes. In `v2`, it return all fields in about method.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer....!
However: I am trying to do this in Python, actually. Would you be able to refactor your answer for that language?

Comment: Actually, I think I understand the flow of the code you wrote here. Transcribing this to python oughtn't be too tricky, especially since I already have the whole OAuth2 working smoothly, and have no problem getting the metadata. This process is substantially similar to the one you described here.